# Module Export: call procedure from oracle then assign global variable and use another files that variable in Node js?

Tags: node.js, oracle

I will call procedure and then I want to assign global variable from dbFunction return object. that global variable work every file so I don't want to clone function. I want call one time use every file. is it possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. When you say, "that global variable work every file so I don't want to clone function.", what do you mean by clone a function? I could be wrong, but I think you will need to export an async function (async/await) which will return a promise. This is because the first time the function is called you'll need to get the result asynchronously. Once you get the result the first time you can just return it afterward. Here's an example https://medium.com/@bluepnume/async-javascript-is-much-more-fun-when-you-spend-less-time-thinking-about-control-flow-8580ce9f73fc

Comment: thank you I'm new  for node js and async code and 
sometimes it can be difficult for me. I did what i want.